# Encrypt all data with nodejs + angularjs + mongoose

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, encryption

I would like to encrypt all the datas that is being saved in mongoose. Do you know some plugins or some moduls, in nodejs, that does this ? And how could i do it efficiently with angularjs in frontend ?

For example : i'm using a chat system, using socket.io. And i store the messages in this model :

```
 var messageSchema = new Schema({
     type: {
      type: String,
      required: false
    },
  user: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
    trim: true
  },
  content: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
      trim: true
  },
  slug: {
      type: String,
      lowercase: true,
      trim: true
  },
  created: Date,
  updated: [Date],
  roomCreator: {
      type: Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Room'
  },
});
```

I want all this data to be encrypted in the most secure way as possible, so nobody should be able to see any of the contents of the messages.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is this:
[**ChatSafe**](https://github.com/DavidTimms/ChatSafe)

Though I am not sure how I feel about it though.  It has the ability to use different cipher keys, but it has no inherent way to get keys from one client to the other, which is necessary to decrypt messages (apparently you have to send them a url, which is how other clients get the cipher key).  It is cool that it does all the encryption client-side though.

I think I would work this one though: **[Implement AES Strength Encryption With JavaScript](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/10/implement-aes-strength-encryption-javascript/)**
It shows you how to build a client-side angular based encryption service.

Encrypt everything client side > shoot it to node > save/do whatever > send it to other clients > decrypt client side.